# Which way does a stone move when hit by a wheel/tire?

Tags: physics, kinematics

I apologize if this question has been asked before, but I haven't been able to find a post which covers this exact question.

Let's say that we have a driving car which is moving forward. At some point, one of the rotating tires hit a stone on the road. Which way does the stone move, in relationship with the angle in which the tire hits the stone? Can the stone ever be thrown backward onto another car?

Does the general direction (forward, backward, sideways) depend furthermore on the shape of the stone? Whether it is for example perfectly spherical or asymmetric?

I am kind of struggling how I would answer such a basic question, since there seems to be many factors at play here. Can you even answer this question without fully knowing all the nuances and details?

Comment: This is a great question, but it belongs on Physics.SE.

Comment: Sounds more like a physics question to me.

Comment: Oh you guys are absolutely right, I apologize for this misjudgement, would you suggest that I close this and reopen it there?

Answer (score 1):

Suppose a rock is lodged in the tread of the tire.

$x=v_xt +  R\cos(\omega t)$

$z=R \sin (\omega t)$

$dx/dt =v_x-\omega R\cos(\omega t)$

Typically, $v_x=\omega R$

So it generally wouldn't go backward, but can be overtaken by a car behind it effectively having the same result.

This implies $dx/dt = 2v_x\sin^2(\omega t/2) \implies dx/dt> 0$

This changes if $v\ne \omega R$, but that's the primary effect.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your wonderful answer! Is it correct that vx = wR is the velocity at the bottom of the tire where it hits the stone? So the maximum possible velocity?

Comment: That's the "without slipping condition".  If the car is peeling out, the tires are rotating pretty fast, but the car isn't going anywhere, that changes things up a bit. Then the rock can move behind the car at a max speed of $\omega R$.

Comment: I see, so in terms of words, is it correct to say that the translational velocity of the tire will dominate over the rotational velocity based on your calculation? Also, what can you say about the angle in which the stone will be displaced? Will it be displaced in the direction of the movement of the car? Or at an angle?

Comment: At an angle I don' think you can't generally determine. The stone is stuck in the tread, it essentially experiences a radially outward force that dislodges, probably at a random, chaotic angle along an initial trajectory tangent to the surface of the tire. If it isn't lodged its still probably "grabbed" a little and getting tossed back at a random angle.

Comment: So the stone would never more in the direction perpendicular to the movement of the tire?

Comment: Depends what you mean, "motion of the tire". There's a couple motions going on at once. There's translational motion of the tire and rotation motion of the stone. It's possible it will dislodge at the same time the speed due to rotational motion is perpendicular to the lateral motion, but extremely unlikely. In fact, since the pressure on the ground slightly distorts the tire, I'd expect the rock to dislodge where the rotational and translational motion are in parallel, but opposite directions.

Comment: Yeah I expect the same, but when that happens, would you then expect the rock to move parallel and in the same direction as the translational motion then?